# Cron job terminates session immediately

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, cron, raspbian, session

I have this entry in cronjob:

```bsh
$ cronjob -l
* * * * * $(cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt)
```

when I run the script manually everything works perfectly fine from everywhere in system.
However, when I run it as cron job, the job starts, but terminates immediately - **therefore terminating my sinatra application**:

```bsh
$ journalctl -u cron.service | tail
Aug 18 09:37:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12180]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user fedor
Aug 18 09:38:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12241]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user fedor by (uid=0)
Aug 18 09:38:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12242]: (fedor) CMD ($(cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt))
Aug 18 09:38:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12241]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 18 09:38:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12241]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user fedor
Aug 18 09:39:01 fedor-desktop cron[3820]: (fedor) RELOAD (crontabs/fedor)
Aug 18 09:39:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12397]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user fedor by (uid=0)
Aug 18 09:39:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12398]: (fedor) CMD (cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt)
Aug 18 09:39:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12397]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 18 09:39:01 fedor-desktop CRON[12397]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user fedor
```

run_mecab.sh:

```bsh
. app.config
echo $PID

if [ -n "$(ps -p $PID -o pid=)" ] && [ "$(ps -q $PID -o comm=)" == "ruby" ]; then
  echo "process is running"
  echo $PID
else
  echo "process is not running, starting"
  bundle exec ruby main.rb -o 0.0.0.0 -p 4568 & 
  ID="$!"
  echo $ID
  echo "PID=$ID" > app.config
fi
```

basically the script just check if the service with id is running and if not it starts one and save the new id.

I had this setup on rpi **raspbian** and it worked fine but on **jetson nano default image** (ubuntu 18.something) the job starts but terminates immediately. I am not sure where to start debuging, I adjusted priviledges for `run_mecab.sh` based on another cron question and did not find anything satisfying for `pam_unix(cron:session): session opened/closed` which helps me understand where could be the problem.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you have `$()` around the cronjob? This will cause `cron` to attempt executing whatever `run_mecab.sh` returns as a command - but you are redirecting its output, so it's trying to execute "nothing".

Comment: Also, this seems like a very complex way to implement a watchdog - is `systemd` installed? If yes, consider creating a `.service`

Comment: Use `* * * * * ( cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh ) >> log.txt 2>&1` and see what error(s) you're getting in the `log.txt`. But this isn't the right way to create a restarting service

Comment: $() should execute command as subprocess. systemd: `Failed to create /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1829.scope/init.scope control group: Permission denied
Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied` What is the correct way to create restarting service? I am amateur with linux, just glueling code from internet. Thanks for any advice. `>> log.txt 2>&1` is returning nothing to log.txt

Comment: My mistake, please try this instead: `* * * * * ( cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh ) >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @roaima now the output is: `/bin/sh: 1: /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto: Permission denied` even with `chmod 7777 on the run_mecab.sh`

Comment: Hang on, why `/bin/sh`? Are you _sure_ this is the _exact_ command you have? Could you be using `sh run_mecab.sh` instead of `bash run_mecab.sh`? Also, please [edit] your question and add the output of  `ls -ld /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/`.

Comment: ls: `drwxrwxr-x 5 fedor fedor 4096 Aug 17 21:48 /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/` no, I am not using sh, I am using bash to execute every shell script... like `bash weather.sh, etc...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of `run_mecab.sh` and calling with:

```
* * * * * $(cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && ./run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt)
```

instead of

```
* * * * * $(cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt)
```

solved my issue. Thank you all for help.

Comment: You still don't want `$()`, that is pointless here. Just use `cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt` or, if you really want a subshell for some reason (but you don't, it wouldn't make sense) use `( cd /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto && bash run_mecab.sh >> /home/fedor/Documents/mecab_natto/log.txt)`, but don't use `$(...)`.

Comment: thanks for poiting out, I will reconsider.

Comment: You're also still not capturing error messages. Use the `2>&1` construct after the log file redirection for that